# Principles of Mathematical Analysis chapter1 appendix step 3

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

[image]

"$\gamma$ is the union of all $\alpha \in A$".

-- Does this mean the $\gamma$ and A the same thing? why define $\gamma$

can anyone help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to think of this in the following way:

The elements of $R$ are not "numbers", but Dedekind cuts of ${\mathbb Q}$, i.e. subsets of ${\mathbb Q}$ with certain properties. If $A\subset R$ then $A$ is a set of cuts: Each $\alpha\in A$ is a set of rational numbers. An upper bound $\beta$ of $A$ is a cut $\beta\in{\mathbb R}$ such that $\alpha\subset\beta$ for all $\alpha\in A$. Note that the set-inclusion $\alpha\subset\beta$ is interpreted as $\alpha\leq\beta$ when interpreting $\alpha$, $\beta$ as "numbers".

Given $A$ the author forms the union $\gamma:=\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}\alpha$. This $\gamma$ is a priori a set of rational numbers. In the quoted text it is then verified that $\gamma$ is in fact a cut, hence $\gamma\in R$.

Etcetera.